# Updating text in a widget on an event

Tags: android, android-widget, textview

I created a class that downloads some text from the internet and I want to take that text and update a `TextView` in my widget. I know that the event (OnDownloadCompleteListener) is getting triggered because I'm Logging it but I can't figure out how to update the TextView from within that event. I know it's a newbie mistake, just not sure what I'm missing.

```
    public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider{

        InternetText internettext; //Handles downloading the text from the internet
        RemoteViews views;

        public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
            final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

            // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this provider
            for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
                int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

                // Create an Intent to launch ExampleActivity
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

                // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener
                // to the button
                views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
                views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.tvWidgetVerse, pendingIntent);

                internettext = new InternetText(context);
                internettext.setOnDownloadCompleteListener(new OnDownloadCompleteListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onEvent() {
                        TheText thetext = internettext.downloadedText(); //The text object
                        Log.i("", "Widget Text Downloaded " + thetext.getText()); //This fires so I know we've downloaded the text
                        TextStyling textStyle = new TextStyling();



//*****THIS IS WHERE I'M HAVING THE PROBLEM********
                        views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvWidgetText, Html.fromHtml(textStyle.boldWords(thetext.getText()))); //this never updates
                    }
                });


                internettext.getText();

                // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current app widget
                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Does  thetext.getText()  return a result in the log when you run the app?

Comment: yeah. everything is working as it should except for setting the text to the textview. No errors are thrown either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. I have to call `appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget()` from within the event. I knew it was a no-brainer...

```
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
```

which also means I have to make appWidgetManager and appWidgetId `final`

```
    public void onUpdate(Context context, final AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
 ...
}
```